React Swiper does not rendering slides when passing slides via children prop
I am trying to build a carousel using swiper, I am trying to pass the SwiperSlide as children of the Swiper in this case it does not render the slides in the browser
here is how I tried:
MyCarousel.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';

interface ComponentProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

function MyCarousel({children}: ComponentProps){
  return (
    <Swiper loop={true} spaceBetween={50} slidesPerView={1}>
      {children}
    </Swiper>
  );
};

export default MyCarousel;

MySlides.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import { SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

function MySlides({ slides }: ComponentProps) {

  return (
    <>
      {slides.map((slide) => (
        <SwiperSlide className="h-full" key={slide.id}>
          <div
            className="h-full bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat blur-3xl"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.src})` }}
          ></div>
          <div className="absolute inset-0 flex h-full justify-center">
            <img src={slide.src} alt={slide.src} />
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

MyPage.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import MySlidesfrom '@components/my-slides'

function MyPage() {

  const slides = [
    { id: 1, src: 'my-image-1.jpg' },
    { id: 2, src: 'my-image-2.jpg' },
    { id: 3, src: 'my-image-3.jpg' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      <CarouselProvider>
        <MySlides slides={slides} />
      </CarouselProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

The above way is not working. It is not working the slides in the DOM as you can see in the screenshot the swiper-wrapper is empty

If I modify MyPage.tsx this way it works as it should-
import React from 'react'

function MyPage() {

  const slides = [
    { id: 1, src: 'my-image-1.jpg' },
    { id: 2, src: 'my-image-2.jpg' },
    { id: 3, src: 'my-image-3.jpg' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      <CarouselProvider>
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <SwiperSlide className="h-full" key={slide.id}>
            <div
              className="h-full bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat blur-3xl"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.src})` }}
            ></div>
            <div className="absolute inset-0 flex h-full justify-center">
              <img src={slide.src} alt={slide.src} />
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </CarouselProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

I am using

"react": "^18.3.1",
"swiper": "^11.1.15",

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Seems like swiper/react iterates over the children. It checks for each child if it is SwiperSlide.
I found a trick that works, but not sure how reliable it is. If the displayName of the direct children is SwiperSlide, it renders them correctly.
function MyCarousel({children}) {
  return (
    <Swiper
     ...
     >
      <Inner>
        {children}
      </Inner>
    </Swiper>
  );
}

// This makes the trick
function Inner({children}) {
  return <>{children}</>
}
Inner.displayName = 'SwiperSlide'  // set the display name!


// Usage:

 function Content() {
     return (
        <>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
       </>
    )
 }

function App() {
  return (
    <MyCarousel>
      <Content />
    </MyCarousel>
  )
}

Edit:
If the above trick does not suit you, you can consider using different technique instead of children component. Like a render prop or utility function
utility function instead of component:
function MyCarousel({children}) {
  return (
    <Swiper
     ...
     >
        {children}
    </Swiper>
  );
}

function makeSlides(slides) {
    return slides.map((slide) => ...view here)
}


function App() {
  return (
    <MyCarousel>
      {makeSlides(slides)}
    </MyCarousel>
  )
}

render prop that renders single slide:
function MyCarousel({slides, renderSlide}) {
  return (
    <Swiper
     ...
     >
        {
            slides.map(renderSlide)
        }
    </Swiper>
  );
}

function renderSlide(slide) {
    return ...single slide view here
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MyCarousel slides={slides} renderSlide={renderSlide} />
  )
}


Thanks @Oki that trick is working, it's loading the slide but conflicting with some options of Swiper!

@mizan3008 I added some different techniques you can use to achieve the same effect.

I figured it out this way!
// MyCarousel.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';

interface ComponentProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

function MyCarousel({children}: ComponentProps){

  const enhancedChildren = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      Children.map(children, (child) =>
        isValidElement(child) ? (
          <SwiperSlide>{cloneElement(child)}</SwiperSlide>
        ) : null
      ),
    [children]
  )

  return (
    <Swiper loop={true} spaceBetween={50} slidesPerView={1}>
      {enhancedChildren }
    </Swiper>
  );
};

export default MyCarousel;

// MySlide.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import { SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

function MySlides({ slide }: ComponentProps) {

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="h-full bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat blur-3xl"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.src})` }}
      ></div>
      <div className="absolute inset-0 flex h-full justify-center">
        <img src={slide.src} alt={slide.src} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

// MyPage.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import MySlidesfrom '@components/my-slides'

function MyPage() {

  const slides = [
    { id: 1, src: 'my-image-1.jpg' },
    { id: 2, src: 'my-image-2.jpg' },
    { id: 3, src: 'my-image-3.jpg' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      <CarouselProvider>
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <MySlide key={slide.id} slide={slide} />
        ))}
      </CarouselProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

